# What is the elementary gate set for ion-trap quantum computers?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, ion-trap-quantum-computing

I asked earlier [Which quantum gates can we use in terms of depth?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12162/which-quantum-gates-can-we-use-in-terms-of-depth). In the question, I asked

> I want to measure the depth of a circuit, but I do not know which quantum gates should be used when the circuit is decomposed.

and the answers is

> depending on hardware.

If we use the quantum computer made of ion trap, what is the gate set, especially two-qubit gate? I have heard that $XX$ rotation is one of them, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of single qubit gates, ion traps rather easily can do any arbitrary rotation on the Bloch sphere - those are all straightforward to do.

For two qubit gates, most trapped ion systems use a variant of the Molmer-Sorenson gate which physically couples spin and motion. Computationally, the Molmer-Sorenson gate corresponds to an $XX$ rotation gate as you described. Although, I should mention that you can easily have a laser setup which is different and get you a Molmer-Sorenson gate which is $YY$ instead. Nonetheless, since single qubit gates are cheap and rather easy with trapped ions, you can change basis to whatever you prefer.

Comment: By "$XX$ gate", I assume you don't mean $X\otimes X$ (which would not be useful), but something like $(I+iX\otimes X)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @DaftWullie It's an $XX$ rotation, i.e. $\exp(i\theta/2 X\otimes X)$